# Understanding maps file in /proc directory for a process

Tags: memory-management

In linux, when I access /proc for a particular program it shows memory mapping for the program in maps file.

Something like this:
[image]

I wanted to know what is this [stack] memory mapped to i.e the kernel stack or the user stack and how can I access the contents inside that memory area?

There is another file within the /proc directory called stack but it is the kernel stack as confirmed by the man page for proc(5)

Also, I wanted to know why there are 2 [heap]s in this process mapping?

I also checked the address range for [stack] of all the threads of a process and found them to be same for all of them. How is this possible when threads do not share stack?

Comment: This question belongs on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).